# Websites where you can input your hand histories for them to give you stats

Tags: hand-history

I have pokerstars hand data for two tournaments I competed in. I know you can give pokerstars hand data to programs like poker tracker 4, but I was wondering if there is a way to get analysis of hand history files from a site (so like you don't have to actually download anything). 
Also, what is the input for these kind of sites, and if programs like pokerstars are the only thing that does it, for programs like that (is it .txt .html). I have a problem too because I asked for my last hundred hands, and I had less than that in the data base so it just cycled to the beginning to get to one hundred.
This is where file type comes into play. If these things just require a text files I can delete those recycled hands, but if it's html I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I used to use Sharkscope back in the day before pstars banned it.   You didn't even ahve to upload your history because they kept track of EVERYONE for you.

You probably should start by seeing if anything in this list works for you...

http://www.toolspoker.com/pokerstars/pokerstars-allowed-poker-tools/

You may also want to review this FAQ...

https://www.pokerstars.com/poker/room/prohibited/

If you don't mind paying some $, this site is pretty good for all things poker data ...

https://www.hhsmithy.com/

This probably isn't exactly what your looking for but it might be useful to you.  It trims your hand histories down to just the important or major hands...

http://poker-tools.flopturnriver.com/Tournament-Hand-History-Converter.php

Hope some of this helps.   Let me know if you find something that works for you as I'm still looking for something after they banned Sharkscope.